# Calculated column in R with lookup from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, analytics

I am pretty new to R and I already created some function but Im kinda lost in here: I need to come up with values of the "Result" column. I currently have a data frame with column names of "Seasons" and "Total". However, I need to add another column "Result". To get this, I need to look up the "multiplier" value from another data frame.

```
Seasons    Total    Result

Winter     200       100
Fall        50        25
Spring      10         5
Summer     120        12
```

I have other data frame with column and row values of

```
Multiplier     Value  
Win1            0.5
Win2            0.1
```

Win1 should only be multiplied to  "Total" when Seasons are Winter, Fall and Spring while Win2 must only be multiplied to "Total" when season is Summer. This should be the value of "Result" column.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `ifelse()`

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
data1 = data.frame(Seasons = c("Winter","Fall","Spring","Summer"),
           Total = c(200,50,10,120),stringsAsFactors = F)
data2 = data.frame(Multiplier = c("Win1","Win2"), Value = c(0.5,0.1), stringsAsFactors = F)

data1$Total = ifelse(data1$Seasons != "Summer", data1$Total[data1$Seasons != "Summer"]*
                       data2[data2$Multiplier%in%"Win1",2],
                     data1$Total[data1$Seasons == "Summer"]*
                       data2[data2$Multiplier%in%"Win2",2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `dplyr` could be as;

```
df1 %>% mutate(Result = ifelse(Seasons %in% c("Winter", "Fall", "Spring"), 
            Total*df2[df2$Multiplier=="Win1",]$Value,
            Total*df2[df2$Multiplier=="Win2",]$Value))

#  Seasons Total Result
#1  Winter   200    100
#2    Fall    50     25
#3  Spring    10      5
#4  Summer   120     12

# OR 2nd Option is using with
df1$Result <- with(df1, ifelse(Seasons %in% c("Winter", "Fall", "Spring"),
              Total*df2[df2$Multiplier=="Win1",]$Value,
              Total*df2[df2$Multiplier=="Win2",]$Value) )
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Seasons    Total
Winter     200
Fall        50
Spring      10
Summer     120", header = T, stringsAsFactor =F)

df2 <- read.table(text = "Multiplier     Value  
Win1            0.5
Win2            0.1", header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse()`

```
df$Result <- ifelse(df$Seasons=="Summer", df2$Value[2]*df$Total, df2$Value[1]*df$Total)
```